# Alter module js for on custom page

Tags: 7, javascript, hooks

I have a small problem with altering js code loaded from custom module. I need to change the js script from a module for a custom page

Module code code :

```
function module_script_src($environment) {
  $script = '';
  $script_id = variable_get('script_id', '');
  $script_hash = variable_get('script_hash', '');
  switch ($environment) {
    case 'prod':
      if ($script_id && $script_hash) {
        $script = '//example.com/' . $script_id . '/lib-' . $script_hash . '.js';
      }
      break;

    case 'dev':
      if ($adobe_dtm && $site_hash) {
        $script = '//example.com/' . $script_id . '/lib-dev' . $script_hash . '.js';
      }
      break;

  }
  return $script;
}
```

The goal is to change $script just for one custom page, i try to add case for my custom page, simply new case to module

```
 case 'custom page':
       if ($node && $node->nid = "my_node_id"):
     $script = '//example.com/' . $script_id . '/custom-' . $script_hash . '-.js';
  }
      break;
```

But it does not work, if it possible in module to load custom is for the specific custom page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the switch statement you provide, you are switching over `$environment` variable. It sounds like it will never be passed a URL or 'custom page' value.

You are also trying to use `$node` object but you have not loaded it from your code. You are also not passing `$node` as an argument. Also an `$adobe_dtm` variable is used but never defined. Plus, you are using `=` to do an equality check, you need `==` or `===`. `=` is assigning 'my_node_id' to your variable instead of compare it.

In order to have a `$node` object present in this function, you need to do one of two things to get it:

- `$node = menu_get_object('node');`
- `$node = node_load(arg(1));`

Then you can just add this after the switch statement:

```
function module_script_src($environment) {
  $script = '';
  $script_id = variable_get('script_id', '');
  $script_hash = variable_get('script_hash', '');

  switch ($environment) {
    case 'prod':
      if ($script_id && $script_hash) {
        $script = '//example.com/' . $script_id . '/lib-' . $script_hash . '.js';
      }
      break;

    case 'dev':
      if ($adobe_dtm && $site_hash) {
        $script = '//example.com/' . $script_id . '/lib-dev' . $script_hash . '.js';
      }
      break;

  }

  if ($node = menu_get_object('node')) {
    if ($node->nid == "my_node_id"):
      $script = '//example.com/' . $script_id . '/custom-' . $script_hash . '-.js';
    }
  }

  return $script;
}
```

You may need to think through the cases involved in building the script value. It looks like the switch statement is not even necessary, because `$script` value is basically the same - in which case you can clean up the code by simplifying it.